# How to zip a huge file in amazon s3 without downloading to local machine

Tags: file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I have a need to zip a huge file which is present in aws s3 bucket ,right now we are downloading to a local ec2 instance and doing the zipping and then uploading back, but it takes lots of time , so want to know what are my options to zip the huge file that is in s3 bucket ?

Comment: S3 is storage. Compression is a compute operation.

Comment: S3 is a storage service, not compute service. To zip it, you need compute. There is no way to zip it without downloading it.

Comment: ok , after downloading it , what are my options to speed up the zipping process , right now we have few terabytes size of file and it takes 9 hours to zip it , is there any quick way to process it ?

Comment: Fire up the fastest EC2 instance you can with the 20GB network card. Create 2 10TB EBS volumes - one for the file and one for the compressed file.  Start compressing :)  EDIT - there are some [multithreaded zip tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/258202/multi-core-compression-tools) too.

Comment: You can use lamda to compress a file and store into another bucket. or/and https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-zip